# how do we prevent dml operations for a specific schema for a specified period of time?

Tags: database, oracle, schema, tablespace

Is there any possible way to prevent dml operations for a specific user schema is busy traffic hours without impacting other user schema's dml operations

Comment: You could lock the account and kill any existing sessions during "busy hours" (or revoke the `create session` privilege rather than locking the account).  That could be automated but it would be a rather crude solution.  Are you sure that you want to truly prevent the user from logging in rather than limiting their ability to issue expensive queries via a profile or lowering their priority for resources using Resource Manager?

Comment: Thanks Justin I wanted to limit ability for a specified user schema ,I thought of triggers but un sure how to control it over a specified time stamp and allow normal access later on

Comment: Limit or prevent?  A job (`dbms_job`, `dbms_scheduler`, `cron`, etc.) could run at a set time and revoke the `create session` privilege, lock the account, and/or kill the existing sessions.  Using a profile or using Resource Manager would be more elegant by limiting the resources the user could consume without preventing them from logging in at all.

Comment: Thanks @JustinCave, read a few definitions of revoking 'create session', seems if i revoke him for a specified time then, it will prevent the schema from establishing a DB connection..so thats a _Prevent_.. and i guess to stick on to _Limit_ i should be going on with Resource Manager right?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on who has grants to insert/update/delete/execute on that user's objects it could be as easy as

```
ALTER USER myuser ACCOUNT LOCK;
ALTER USER myuser PASSWORD EXPIRE;
```

and then unlock and unexpire once you're done.

If other users have access to that schema then I don't think there is a simple way.